# Best database structure for this SaaS

Tags: mysql, database

I'd like to start a brainstorming with this post ... before ask my question, let me go into the scenario:

I'm going to build a software service, it's will be a CRM-like web-based software.
So, everyone can subscribe to the service and, as logged user, you can have one or more CONTACTS and one or more EMPLOYEES (employees can sign-in too).

The software is CONTACT centered ... every contact can have PROJECTS, DOCUMENTS, and so on.

NOW THE QUESTION:
In order to build a secure and easy to maintain software, this time I was thinking to use separate database. What do you think about having a database dedicated for each subscriber?

Why I ask this question?
Well ... The service will have a custom version. This means that a single user (that has subscribed to the service) can have a VERY VERY personalized version, this customization will touch EVERY layer:

- DB structure
- Model classes
- Views (this is the easies part)
- Controllers

Seems that it's going to be a different application.

I was thinking to keep a master database where all users can login ... and then connect to their private database.

I saw a lot of service out there that also use a personal login page, with a third level domain, like: yourcompany.service.com

Looking to their urls, seems that they use this approach, because we can find something like this:

yourcompany.service.com/contact/1

that shows the details page for a single (first) contact (with ID 1).
Seems that it's the first record of the contacts table.

Otherwise, I can keep one database and control everything with the user_id. So, for example, having a single contacts tables to store ALLL the contacts of ALLLLL my users ... and write a custom one only when needed.

I'm stuck ... I have ever worked with one database for one app, but I'd like to give a chance to another approach.

Have you ever faced this problem? 
How would you solve it?

Comment: narrow down your question and perhaps u want to use http://dba.stackexchange.com/ instead

Comment: Thanks Prix ... Do you know if I can "copy and paste" it in dba section?

Comment: Why have separate databases if every one can be connected to each other as a contact? That’s going to be horrific to maintain. Also, what if you get a million customers? Do you really want to be maintaining a million databases (plus any ‘master’ databases you mention)?

Answer (score 0):

Most owner-operated systems like this (as opposed to user-operated) use multitenant (multi-customer) databases rather than an individual database per customer. That's because there are significant economies of scale in the labor of administering fewer data base instances. (In other words, managing a separate bunch of tables for each customer is a huge and unscalable pain in the neck.)

WordPress is an interesting example of both.  They have a multisite system, where several different users share a database. They use that on their SaaS WordPress.com system. They also have a single site configuration, which individual users can administer themselves.

Comment: Interesting ... so, if I understood, you could use different "plans" where common users use a single database (shared), and when VIP user is coming, you can sort out a private database?

Answer (score 0):

In Postgresql and other many other database you can use have different schemas this allows an isolated way of SAAS

Normally one would use just the main public schema however there in no limit to the number of schemas. So in other words you can have a schema for each customer.

example

www.example.com would see the public schema/tenant

mycustomername.example.com would see public and mycustomername schema/tenant

Alot of web frameworks have this built in or as a third party app